# Join Table B to Table A, where Table B is an audit history, and only want the most recent Table B entry that is before a date on Table A

Tags: sql, t-sql

SQL Server 2008 R2 (yup, we are past the extended support date)

**Table A** has a VendorID and a date.  Each VendorID is present only one time.

A snippet of **Table B** is below. Table B can have the same VendorID multiple times, with various dates.  (It shows a history of the VendorID status.)

[image: Table B]

How can I join Table B to Table A, such that I get the most recent entry for Table B, that is less than the date for that row in Table A?

Say if I wanted just "give me the most recent entry from Table B, by vendor ID, that is before data 'yyyy-mm-dd' - not so bad.  I could use a window function, then just join it to Table A.

But I don't want to do this for a single date, the data would vary by the date in the row for table A.

-- Example for if I were grabbing the most recent entry from Table B, by VendorId, by a *set* date.  Then I could just join the results, no problem.

```
select 
    sq.VendorId
    ,sq.PaymentType

from ( 
    select 
        a.VendorId
        ,a.PaymentType
        ,row_number() over (partition by a.vendorid order by createdateutc 
 desc) as rn 

from  
    ZpCustomers_Kim.dbo.VendorListPaymentTypeChangeAudit a  --**Table B**

WHERE 
    CreateDateUTC < '2019-05-09' 

 ) sq

where 
    sq.rn = 1
```

But if I want to, instead of using '2019-05-19', have the date depend on the date in the row for **Table A**, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your query has to do with the question.  But you can do what you want with `apply`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a outer apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from b
      where b.VendorID = a.VendorID and
            b.date <= a.date
      order by d.ate desc
     ) b;
```

Comment: I had to fix my formatting (thus, possibly the query looking unrelated), but I think that's it - thanks!